# how asp form is processed?

Tags: asp.net

Could some body pleases explain me how asp form is processed in asp.net.
I mean when i click the URL having asp.net page address how it works, how it is processed to the production server and how it retrieves data to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx